# REST and Building Forms that Redirect

Tags: rest

I'm build an application along RESTful principles.  I have a user-facing form that POSTS to create a new comment, the URL for that action is POST {article}/comment

After the POST happens, I want to redirect the user to GET {article}/thanks

But I'm not sure how to implement this.  It seems un-RESTful for the POST {article}/comment resource to also have the logic knowing about the next step for the underlying {article}

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider applying [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) principles to submit your form, receive a success/fail/other response from the server, and to take further action (redirect) based on that response.

You will find a lot of help using some frameworks like jQuery that will help posing your form and process responses, take a look at this [blog post](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/03/rest.html), especially its consume part.